# How do browsers calculate the resolution of the phone?

Tags: html, css, web, browser, web-deployment

If you go to any phone specifications on any website they usually have resolutions like:

- 1080 x 2340 pixels, 19.5:9 ratio (~409 ppi density)
- 720 x 1280 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~294 ppi density)

But using the same phones and going to a website that uses max-width of 600px, the media query still works. Also when checking the resolution on whatismyresolution it says that the width is 360px and the height is around 700px on both phones. How is the resolution calculated on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

To get the resolution of a mobile device we need to multiply the screen width and height with the device pixel ratio.

i.e. window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio and window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio.

Re the media query does works with max and min width as well as height , so we can define the resolution accordingly in css or less code if we target any specific resolution to support or target.